# UK Visitor Visa Email

Tags: uk, application-status

So after an anxious 15 working days wait, I sent in an enquiry via the UK International Enquiry website last night and received this reply

"I have tracked the status GWF#-xx/xx/xxxx and
found that the application has been processed and a decision has been made"

Now that probably means that the decision office in Manila (mine's sent there for processing) has made a decision. Maybe I'm reading too much into this but from what I've read (on other blogs of people in my region) & from the VFS website itself, usually the UKVI embassy will send an email stating that the decision has been made.

This is from the VFS website itself "You should wait till you receive an email from British Embassy in Manila where the decision is made. You are to allow 3 days for the passport to be received at the Visa Application Centre."

However, for my case the manila embassy did not send any email & I only found out the decision has been made because of the enquiry. Is this something to be worried about?

Comment: @pnuts this should be an answer. (Personal, semi-related anecdote, try to imagine the feeling when after a three year long struggle to gain citizenship the website says "decision made" but it doesn't say *what* the decision is! It took days to get the decision in mail.)

Comment: A visa decision is a deeply personal matter subject to both regulation and long established policy. It's utterly and completely private between them and the applicant and they observe strict formalities. Because of that they will never ever reveal the actual decision in a status update and you should be grateful for their discretion.  Find something else to worry about.

Comment: I'm voting to close because there is no answerable question, here.

Answer (score 7):

Converting comments into an answer:

First my own, although not the same country, I had similar experience when the Canadian immigration website showed "decision made" after a three year struggle to gain citizenship. What the decision *is* only came to light when the physical mail has arrived a few days later.

Second, pnuts points out since you can't do a thing, there's nothing to do but wait. Above anecdote corroborates.

GayotFow points out, arriving to the same conclusion: A visa decision is a deeply personal matter subject to both regulation and long established policy. It's utterly and completely private between them and the applicant and they observe strict formalities. Because of that they will never ever reveal the actual decision in a status update and you should be grateful for their discretion. Find something else to worry about.